# Handle dismissed Firebase notification in Android System Tray

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the **onMessageReceived** method I'm saving some data in the local database.

If the app is in **background** when I tap on the notification, it redirects me to the launcher activity. There I'm processing the incoming data from the **Bundle** and save it in the local database.

How can I handle when the user dismisses the notification? *Because if the user dismisses the notification the data I receive from the server is lost.*

Comment: why don't you save data as soon as it receives in onmessageReceived?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I save it as soon as the data is received. But if the app is in background onMessageReceived is not being called anymore.

Comment: because, you are using Notification. instead use Data method for FCM, it call onMessageReceived every time

Comment: this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use BroadCast Reciever to save data when it is received check out this link:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the dismissal by adding deleteIntent to your notification builder.
use the intent, add data that you received to it and redirect it to the handler class.
In the handler class extract data and save to db :)

```
mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this.context, YourHandlingClass.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed when removing the notification and used DATA method for fcm.

thank you @DivyeshPatel

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can directly save data to local db in onMessageReceived rather than waiting for user to open notifications.

**2.** Disable the auto-cancel

```
notication.setAutoCancel(false)
```